# Accordion wont work when i delete accordion__content div from my HTML. Any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this nested accordion, and if i dont have the parent, the accordion doesnt work at all. Its not really accordion, its more of a multilevel navbar of a sort. I need help, but in pure JAVASCRIPT, please dont post answers in jQuery, thank you very much. Also, if you could help me refactor my html so that i can delete the `accordion__content` class, that would mean a world, thank you.

```js
const accordionItem = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion--item");

const parent = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

const accordionContent = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion__content");

for (let i = 0; i < accordionItem.length; i++) {
    
  if (innerWidth > '1000') {
    accordionItem[i].addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      for (let j = 0; j < accordionItem.length; j++) {
        accordionItem[j].classList.remove("accordion--open");
        accordionContent[j].style.display = "none";
      }
      let parentEl = accordionItem[i].parentElement.parentElement;
     ;
      while (parentEl && parentEl.classList.contains("accordion--item")) {
        parentEl.classList.add("accordion--open");
        parentEl.children[1].style.display = "block";
        parentEl = parentEl.parentElement.parentElement;
        if (accordionContent[i].parentElement.parentElement.innerHTML === "") {
          accordionContent[i].parentElement.classList.remove("accordion--open");
        }
      }
      accordionItem[i].classList.add("accordion--open");
      accordionContent[i].style.display = "block";
    });
    accordionItem[i].addEventListener("mouseout", (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      accordionContent[i].style.display = "none";
      accordionItem[i].classList.remove("accordion--open");
    });
  } else {
    accordionItem[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      for (let j = 0; j < accordionItem.length; j++) {
        accordionItem[j].classList.remove("accordion--open");
        accordionContent[j].style.display = "none";
      }
      let parentEl = accordionItem[i].parentElement.parentElement;
      c
      while (parentEl && parentEl.classList.contains("accordion--item")) {
        parentEl.classList.add("accordion--open");
        parentEl.children[1].style.display = "block";
        parentEl = parentEl.parentElement.parentElement;
        if (accordionContent[i].textContent === "") {
          accordionContent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
      accordionItem[i].classList.add("accordion--open");
      accordionContent[i].style.display = "block";
    });
  }
}
```

```css
/**
 * Required CSS 
 */
 .accordion__title {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .accordion__icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 24px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  
  .accordion__icon .line-01,
  .accordion__icon .line-02 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 16px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #272343;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .accordion__icon .line-02 {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  
  .accordion__content {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .accordion--open > .accordion__title .line-02 {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  /* end Required CSS */
  
  /**
   * Now let's make it look pretty! 
   */
  body {
    font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
    max-width: 768px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #111;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 40px;
  }
  
  .accordion {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .accordion__title {
    padding: 20px 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
  
  .accordion__content {
    padding: 24px 16px;
  }
  
  .accordion__content p {
    margin: 0 0 16px;
  }
  
  .accordion__title:hover {
    background-color: #433d6f;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .accordion__title:hover .line-01,
  .accordion__title:hover .line-02 {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .accordion--open > .accordion__title {
    background-color: #272343;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .accordion--open > .accordion__title .line-01,
  .accordion--open > .accordion__title .line-02 {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .accordion--nested .accordion__title {
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  .accordion--nested .accordion__content {
    padding: 24px 16px 16px;
  }
  .slideUp {
    height: 0;
  }
  .slideDown {
    height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion--item ">
            <h4 class="accordion__title">
                Parent
            </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Child

                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        Child of child
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 01 -->
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Child

                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 01 -->
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Child 2

                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                            <h4 class="accordion__title">
                                Child of child 2
        
                            </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                            <div class="accordion__content">
                                Child of child 2
                            </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                        </div><!-- end .accordion nested 02 -->
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 02 -->
                <div class="accordion--item accordion--nested">
                    <h4 class="accordion__title">
                        Child

                    </h4><!-- end .accordion__title -->
                    <div class="accordion__content">
                        
                    </div><!-- end .accordion__content -->
                </div><!-- end .accordion nested 01 -->
            </div>
            <!-- end .accordion__content -->
        </div><!-- end .accordion 01 -->

       
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of `accordion__content`? It's a necessary element for that accordion to function.

Comment: @Cerbrus It is, but then, when i leave it blank, i just get a empty div, and it makes spaces, like it has something inside, which i dont need, and im trying to see if there is a way to make that happen, or maybe try some `if` statements so that i can see if its empty to have `display:none`